# Importing table into existing table in a hosted database using filezilla

Tags: php, mysql, database

I added (i.e. inserted) a record into 'users' table in my localhost. I imported the table into the `public_html` using Filezilla. I opened the hosting site Cpanel, opened FTP file manager, opened `public_html`, edited the 'users' table to use the hosting site database name.

I went back to Cpanel, opened phpMyAdmin, refreshed the database and opened the 'users' table. But the record I inserted into the 'users' table was not inserted. Please help.

Comment: You will need to execute the sql commands in `phpMyAdmin`. Open `phpMyAdmin`, select the database then click on the `sql` icon that allows you to run queries. On your local system, export the table in question ( `users` ) so that it exports either just the data or, if the table on the live server does not exist, the table structure and data. Export to Clipboard is easy. On the live site in `phpMyAdmin` - paste this sql into the available textarea and `run` or `submit`

Comment: Thank you Unheilig RamRaider. After exporting the table from my localhoast, i opened the table, copied the insert portion of the query, pasted it as you said, edited the error messages that came up as a result of my table structure and submitted, and it worked. Thank you and God bless